# How to update post taxonomies (Creating a custom UI for Custom Taxonomy)

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I have a taxonomy eg. authors. I want to create a custom UI for. I think integrating with a Meta Box together with other post meta will make things easier for the user. Also I think a jQuery UI AutoComplete (Multiple comma separated values) is more appropriate

So I will need to know how I can "update_post_taxonomy". I suppose I will need to

- if taxonomy does not exists

  - create it
- if post does not have the taxonomy term

  - add it
- remove terms that are not specified by user

I am sure there are functions for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you are looking for is [**`wp_set_post_terms()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_post_terms)

which can create the terms if they don't exists and you can specify if to appended or replace existing terms.  so you can remove all none user terms.

as for

> if post does not have the taxonomy term , add it

you can use [**`wp_get_post_terms()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms) to check if the post has any terms of that taxonomy and if not then you can create and add using `wp_set_post_terms()` once again

Comment: `wp_set_post_terms` will check & add if terms exists for the post right? So I dont need to use `wp_get_post_terms`? Thats what I understand from the 1st part of your answer

Comment: `wp_set_post_terms` will set the term and if it doesn't exists it will create it and then set it,  `wp_get_post_terms` you can use to check if any term is set to that post

Comment: What am I supposed to pass into the `$tags` argument? Term name or slug? Or will WordPress automatically resolve it?

Comment: should work with both as far as i know